# Am I on a RadTab and if I am am I active?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, rad-controls

OK, let's pretend...(I wish)

So there is a Rad Date control, wrapped up in an ASP.NET user control, on the load event of the user control it adds an onblur attribute to the Date control.

Now this control is then added to a tab of Rad Tab control, I change to a different tab, I then click on the menu on the website (which is on a parent iframe, yes it get's worse)

The onblur event actually fires, even though the control did not have focus.  So question is can I, in javascript:

1. detect if the control is actually on a Rad Tab
2. detect which Rad Tab it is on
3. decide then if it is not on the active tab and does not have focus, so don't fire the onblur.

Comment: what? anything, like clapping my hands?

Comment: show us your code if you have written something.or the links you checked.if you have done nothing then check this link http://stackoverflow.com/help and learn how to ask a question